# List all users from tblUsers (table 1) w/ or w/o any records from tblRequests (table 2)

Tags: mysql

How do I get all the "tblusers.username" from table 1.. plus the sum of "tblleaverequest.lqTotalHours" from Table 2 (if "tblleaverequest.lqTotalHours" record is missing, then still show all users, but with 0)

- John 10
- Jim 15
- Sally 0
- Jane 8

  ```
  SELECT
  tblleaverequest.lqUser,
  tblusers.username,
  tblleaverequest.lqTotalHours

  FROM
  tblusers
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblleaverequest ON tblleaverequest.lqUser = 
  tblusers.username
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A right join will include all records from the table right of `RIGHT JOIN`. The right table in your query is `tblleaverequest`. But you want to include all records from `tblusers` which is left of it. So change it to a left join. To replace `NULL`s with `0` use `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT tblleaverequest.lquser,
       tblusers.username,
       coalesce(tblleaverequest.lqtotalhours, 0) lqtotalhours
       FROM tblusers
            LEFT JOIN tblleaverequest
                      ON tblleaverequest.lquser = tblusers.username;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Join help, but when I add my "WHERE 
 YEAR(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())" I only get the the users "with" records in related table again?

Comment: @jlig: Of course. You're asking the DBMS to only give you records where the year of the date is that of the current day. For the records where there is no in the 2nd table there is no date (it's `NULL`) the years don't match.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question: 1) I need to list out all users. 2) then Sum their hours for 2019. (If they have no hours for 2019, then return 0)

Comment: @jilg: Then edit your question and also include the tables structure as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the expected result with that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

(Since this question is not yet closed, with no accepted answer, we can assume that this question is still in need of an answer.)

---

Query pattern to return the specified result would be something like this:

```
  SELECT u.username
       , IFNULL( SUM(r.lqtotalhours) ,0)  AS totalhours
    FROM user u
    LEFT
    JOIN leave_request r
      ON r.lquser        = u.username
     AND r.lqstartdate  >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-01-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY
   GROUP
      BY u.username
```

---

That returns all rows from `user`, along with matching rows from `leave_request`.

With an outer join, when there are no matching rows, we can think in terms of the DBMS generating a matching row to satisfy the join, and that row consists of all NULL values.

The `GROUP BY` clause collapses the rows.

The `SUM` aggregate function totals up the values from the collapsed rows.

Where `user` that didn't have any matching `leave_request`, we are going to get a NULL value.  We can use the MySQL `IFNULL` function to replace a NULL value with a 0.

Note that if we add a `WHERE` clause that requires a non-NULL value for rows return from the outer joined table (`r`),  i.e.

```
 WHERE r.lqstartdate >= '2019-01-01'
```

That will negate the outerness of the join, rendering it equivalent to an inner join. Any  generated rows to sit in for missing rows are going to consist entirely of NULL values.